# Editing a edittext in an xml from button in other xml file (TabLayout)

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a tablayout where have two tabs for now. One tab has a button,editText and another has a ediText. When I press the button I need to read the text from the another tab and put it in current edittext. But when I try this, I've been getting a force close error.For testing I tried putting the content of the editText to the button name.

package android.work;

```
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.res.Resources;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TabHost;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            public class tabcontent1 extends Activity
            {
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {       
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    //TextView txt=new TextView(this);
                    //txt.setText("Tab1");
                    setContentView(R.layout.tab1content);

                    final Button but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                    {

                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                            String str=ed.getText().toString();
                            EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                            but.setText(str);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're not getting nullpointerexception...

Comment: When I checked the logcat.I have a nullpointer exeception.I'm only getting it because of code in the onclicklistener.

Comment: Look what you're doing: You're trying to call findViewById(R.id.editText2); in first activity, but as I understood editText2 is a part of second activity, am I right?

Comment: Yeah...so how do I call the control in the second activity.

Comment: I suppose it's just a  really bad idea to use Activies for such thing. Consider using ViewPager, you'll have much more faster and smooth UI, with cool look and feel experience . To use it you will need compability library, you can find instructions how to use it here http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Great...I will be at it.Thanks